# How do network computers access our data and desktop?

Tags: security, networking

I heard that no root passwords on the system can be a path for my network colleges to have an access to my computer,but when I use My Network Places and click those computers which do not have any passwords I can only access what they share.
So how do we say that we can access their computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, Opening start menu run, type \\Computername\c$ this will allow you to access the root if there is no passwords.